# Build zeppelin-0.7.0 master branch with spark 2.0 failed with 'yarn install --no-lockfile' failed

Tags: build, apache-zeppelin

i tried to build the zeppelin-0.7.0 master branch downloaded from github, but failed .
the build command:

```
  mvn  package  -Pyarn -Pbuild-distr -Pspark-2.0 -Dspark.version=2.0.1  -Phadoop-2.6  -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -Pscala-2.11 -Ppyspark -DskipTests -X
```

the output stacktrace is:

```
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.397 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-14T11:39:00+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/228M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:yarn (yarn install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'yarn install --no-lockfile' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:yarn (yarn install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run task
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'yarn install --no-lockfile' failed. (error code 1)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.YarnTaskExecutor.execute(YarnTaskExecutor.java:61)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.YarnMojo.execute(YarnMojo.java:65)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:89)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I found a lot but no info about this error. Thanks in advance for helping me figure out the reason.

Comment: frontend-maven-plugin should install yarn and `yarn install --no-lockfile` should work. Could you add -X option to the maven command and share the result?

Answer (score 1):

Try to downgrade your node version to node 6 and compile again.
After compilation, upgrade your node version.

Comment: the zeppelin-web module use node V6.9.1 by default, so should node still need downgrade to 6?    could you give more detail about the build process. thanks

Comment: @xu Bruce I have got the same error with node 7. What I have done is to downgrade node version.  `| => node -v` gives
v6.9.4
`| => npm -v` gives
3.10.10 `| => cd zeppelin/` to verify zeppelin version do   `| => grep SNAPSHOT pom.xml` that gives:
  `<version>0.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`
`| => ./dev/change_scala_version.sh 2.11`
`| => mvn clean package -DskipTests -Pspark-2.0 -Phadoop-2.7 -Pyarn -Ppyspark -Psparkr -Pr -Pscala-2.11`

Comment: sorry for later feedback... Thx for your answer. I will try your answer and reply asap.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue-- I ended up installing all the various npm bits that kept failing by running:

```
$ sudo npm install -g bower grunt grunt-cli npm-run-all rimraf webpack
```

Also the build attempt didn't like that I ran it initially as sudo/root (on a test machine), so I recursively changed ownership of /opt/zeppelin (where I extracted the zeppelin tarball) to a regular user 'zeppelin', then ran the maven build command as user zeppelin at /opt/zeppelin.  This was able to get me unblocked, hopefully this may help you too.

Comment: I builded the latest master branch of zeppelin from github, it  passed. You can have a try.