# Unable to build Zeppelin from source - fails with error ""

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

To install Zeppelin from source (on Mac OS X, node version 6.9.1), I am following the directions [on Zeppelin site](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/install/build.html).

When I execute the following command:

```
mvn -e -X clean package -DskipTests
```

while inside the cloned Zeppelin repository, the build fails with the following error:

```
[INFO] Zeppelin: Scio ..................................... SUCCESS [ 33.429 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: web Application .......................... FAILURE [05:51 min]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Server ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Jupyter Support .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 09:58 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-17T17:53:12-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 355M/1803M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:yarn (yarn install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'yarn install --no-lockfile' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:yarn (yarn install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run task
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'yarn install --no-lockfile' failed. (error code 1)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.YarnTaskExecutor.execute(YarnTaskExecutor.java:61)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.YarnMojo.execute(YarnMojo.java:65)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:89)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :zeppelin-web
```

I am aware of [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646832/build-zeppelin-0-7-0-master-branch-with-spark-2-0-failed-with-yarn-install-no), but I must confess that I don't understand how they solved that similar issue.

Update (in response to a proposed answer): Node is installed on my system:

```
(master)$ node --version
v6.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This build failure caused when nodeJS is not installed in your local system.
yarn uses npm. So if you try to  install yarn without npm, then it fails.

https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin-web/pom.xml#L70-L71

Comment: Thanks for this response. As I stated in my questions originally, node 6.9.1 is installed on my local system.